# When restart batch job on spring cloud data flow it starts from beginning

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I run my spring batch job on spring cloud data flow (kubernetes platform). After failed the job, i want to restart where it left off but new job starts from beginning.

Job firstly gets file from Sftp and writes to database. I changed input file 3rd record with incorrect input. After launched task it processed until 3rd record. After restart, it started from first record. How can i restart passing until 3. record ?

Thank you.

Customized base job builder:

```
  public class BaseJobBuilderFactory extends JobBuilderFactory {
  private JobExecutionListener[] listeners;

  public BaseJobBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository, JobExecutionListener... listeners) {
    super(jobRepository);
    this.listeners = listeners;
  }

  public JobBuilder get(String name) {
    JobBuilder jobBuilder = super.get(name);
    jobBuilder.validator(new JobIdValidator());
    jobBuilder.incrementer(new JobIdIncrementer());
    JobExecutionListener[] var3 = this.listeners;
    int var4 = var3.length;

    for(int var5 = 0; var5 < var4; ++var5) {
      JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener = var3[var5];
      jobBuilder = (JobBuilder)jobBuilder.listener(jobExecutionListener);
    }

    return jobBuilder;
  }
}
```

Job configuration:

```
 @Bean
  public Job MyJob() {
    return baseJobBuilders().get("MyJob")
        .flow(sftpGetRemoteFileStep())
        .next(applicationStep())
        .end()
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: What does you `JobIdIncrementer` do?

Comment: This question inspired me to delete JobIdIncrementer and use RunIdIncrementer instead. And it works perfectly. Now the problem is skipping the incorrect file record, because it starts from this:) Thank you.

Comment: That's where I wanted to come by asking this question :-) You were adding a parameter in each run and ending up having a different job instance each time.